# How can I extend the line BC from B and C (both nodes) as per the given code

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I extend the line BC from B and C (both nodes)?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0)--(0,0) node{A}--(4,0)node{B}--(0,4)node{C}--(0,0)--(0,-2) (0,0)--(0,5) (0,0)--(5,0); 
\fill[red] (4,0)--(0,4)--(0,0) [start angle=0,end
angle=90] |- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: hand drawn sketch of what is the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use shorten `>=<length>` and `shorten <=<length>` and provide a negative length:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,0)--(0,0) node[below left]{A}--(4,0)node(b){B}--(0,4)node(c){C}--(0,0)--(0,-2) (0,0)--(0,5) (0,0)--(5,0); 
\fill[red] (4,0)--(0,4)--(0,0) [start angle=0,end
angle=90] |- cycle;
\draw [shorten >= -5cm, shorten <=-5cm] (b)--(c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , it's great... I am very thankful to you, God bless you.... Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

It is quit unusual, that labels of corners are covered by color of shape. I would your image redesign as follows:

[image]

With use of the `positioning` TikZ library is used relative coordinates, which enable to construct relative simple code for image:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.style = {draw, shorten >=-12mm, shorten <=-12mm}]
\coordinate[label=below  left:A] (a);
\coordinate[label=below:B,right=4cm of a] (b);
\coordinate[label= left:C,above=4cm of a] (c);
\fill[red] (a) --(b)--(c);
\draw (a) edge (b) (b) edge(c) (c) edge (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```